# Show first role for each Identity user in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In a controller returning a list of all Identity users I wish to be able to find a users role (have only 1 per user), and include that in the view being able to show "Role" as a column next to the user in the view.

Tried different types of lambda expressions, but unfortunately without luck.

"ApplicationUser" is a new model class adding a couple of new fields to IdentityUser table.

I have set a filter on UserName, and the code works for this specific table.

Here is my action so far:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
return View(await _db.ApplicationUser.Where(u => u.UserName != "-").ToListAsync());
}
```

I have tried to experiment with the "Include" expression, but it doesn't work for me.

Wonder if I need a ViewModel for this purpose, or a lambda expression can do it for me?

I expect to be able to show a table in a view showing fx. username, phone number and role name for each user

Comment: What is the issue you are experiencing? Is the data not being returned in your controller? Is it being retrieved in your controller and not being passed to your view? Are only certain properties being passed to your view? Please expand on the exact issue you are experiencing? Don't force people to search and assume your model properties, detail that information in your question.

Comment: When a new user is created does that also create a user in your ApplicationUser table, with matching IDs?

Comment: Travis: Thanks for your help. My problem is that I'm not able to create the correct lambda expression for my purpose, and I'm not even sure if it's possible to create such an expression? My view is very simple and works, but I need help to extend that to be able to get access to the role name in the view so I can present this along with the user.

Comment: Kevin: Thanks for your help. No, ApplicationUser is just a couple of additional fields to the user itself - nothing related to the user/role